# How to change page CSS based on parent menu item?

Tags: hooks, theming

I'm building a fairly simple site, and I need to alter a background image based on what section the user is in. The main menu only has 2 levels. I'm unsure where I should hook into in order to be able to get the current section (i.e. the root menu item of the current page, see example below) so I can adjust the classes on the page. I was looking at [this article](https://drupal.org/node/1571308) as a possible solution, but I only want to alter CSS classes, and that seems like an awful lot of code for such a simple task.

```
Main Manu:
-- Section 1
   --- Page A
   --- Page B
   --- Page C
-- Section 2
   --- Page D
   --- Page E <- Active page, CSS class "section_2"
   --- Page F
```

Comment: If your theme is any good, you will find a lot of information in classes on `<body>` element, and in classes on all `<div>` elements. Open your site in Firebug or similar tool and see. Maybe the classes you need are already there?

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap as the sub-theme. There are quite a few classes on body, but they're actually too specific, i.e. there's `page-node-70' as a class, but I need to figure out what that node's root menu item is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module. This easily allowed me to add a custom class to the body depending on a selected top-level menu item. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If it is just additional classes you need, you can add additional and unique classes to menu items using the [Menu CSS Names](https://drupal.org/project/menu_css_names) or [Menu Attributes](https://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) modules.

Or, you can effect the element of another DIV on hover using pure CSS like below...

HTML

```
<a id="menu-item" href="#">Menu Item</a>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Change This Background</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background:blue;
}

#menu-item:hover + #container {
    background:red;
}
```

See Fiddle here... [Affect Another Div on Hover](http://jsfiddle.net/UAAF9/)

Comment: I need to alter the classes on another element outside of the menu. I could do this with JavaScript very easily, but it seems like something Drupal should be able to make possible on the server.

Comment: Please see updated answer for CSS only solution.